# Convert double from scientific notation

Tags: java, type-conversion

This is what I've tried.

```
long varOne = 902621492492L;
double varTwo = (double) varOne * 0.0001;
System.out.println(varTwo);
```

Output: 9.02621492492E7. Why isn't it 90262149.2492 and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Uh... it _is_ that number...

Comment: You might want to take a look at [number formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: That's called [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).  It's a different way of representing the number you want to see.  To change the representation, look into the [NumberFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky prior to java 1.6 there exist the deadly number, calll Double.parse() on it, and the VM hangs in an endless loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output: 9.02621492492E7. and  90262149.2492 represent the same number.

Comment: How does 9 and 90m represent the same number?
Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yes, you are.  The number is given in scientific notation.  The `E` has special meaning.  Please do some research.  You can read about scientific notation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Answer (score 0):

should be able to do

```
long varOne = 902621492492L;
double varTwo = varOne.doubleValue() * 0.0001;
System.out.println(varTwo);
```

but from what I can tell `9.02621492492E7` is the answer.

Comment: i think doubleValue() can be used if is as the object Long but for the primitive types there is none. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Oneb for primitives there is the cast operator: (double), which is not needed here

Comment: @AlexWien yes, thank you. what im trying to point out is that `varOne.doubleValue()` produces an error because varOne is a primitive long. just a cent.